# Entity Inserts instead of Update

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In my web i am retrieving a question object **Including** the subcategories it falls in and the language related data.  It also has the QuestionID that is Primary Key for Question. I place this object in PageSession and modify the properties if user wants to.

```
using (var bo = new BL.QuestionBO())
{
    var question = bo.Get(QuestionID);
    PageSession.CurrentQuestion = question;
}   

public Question Get(long QuestionID)
{
    return DataSource.Questions
        .Include(q => q.TransQuestions)
        .Include(q => q.SubCategories)
        .FirstOrDefault(q => q.QuestionID == QuestionID);
}
```

When I add the object back to the DataContext it adds a new object instead of updating the privious one.

```
DataSource.Questions.Add(QuestionEnt);
DataSource.SaveChanges();
```

Am i missing something or coding wrongly?

I have below areas in which i may be wrong.

1. The data context objects are different while retrieving an object.
2. I am using Questions.Add()
3. The proxy object may be don't care about insert/update.

Below is the class generated by .edmx

```
    public partial class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        this.ChallengeDetails = new HashSet<ChallengeDetail>();
        this.TransQuestions = new HashSet<TransQuestion>();
        this.SubCategories = new HashSet<SubCategory>();
    }

    public long QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionTypeID { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int InsertedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChallengeDetail> ChallengeDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransQuestion> TransQuestions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: just curious, you want to update the data, why call the Add method?

Comment: that's all i know :p, don know how to update

Comment: do you use identity column in the database for QuestionID?

Comment: yes i have managed it in database and just created the edmx model by option "Update model from database" but i think it doesn't set the key property in generated class as i gave the class definition.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the reason.

> The reason it happens is that when you use the DbSet.Add method (that
>   is, Screencasts.Add), not only is the state of the root entity marked
>   “Added,” but everything in the graph that the context was not
>   previously aware of is marked Added as well. Even though the developer
>   may be aware that the Topic has an existing Id value, Entity Framework
>   honors its EntityState (Added) and creates an Insert database command
>   for the Topic, regardless of the existing Id.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

To update an entity, here are the options you could do.

## 1. Option A, Change the State

```
DataSource.Entry(QuestionEnt).State = EntityState.Modified;
DataSource.SaveChanges();
```

## 2. Option B, Get the entity from context

```
var questionEntDb = DataSource.Questions.Find(QuestionEnt.QuestionID);
questionEntDb.PropertyA = QuestionEnt.PropertyA;
questionEntDb.PropertyB = QuestionEnt.PropertyB;
questionEntDb.PropertyC = QuestionEnt.PropertyC;
DataSource.SaveChanges();
```

When you call `Add` method,  even though it has the existing Id, the state of the entity becomes `Added` and if you call `Attach`after calling `Add`, the state becomes `Unchanged`. In this case, it will not do the insert nor the update.

```
// State = Detached
DataSource.Questions.Add(QuestionEnt); // -> State = Added
DataSource.Questions.Attach(QuestionEnt); // -> State = Unchanged
DataSource.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes i now used Attach and it still doesn't work. My code goes below. DataSource.Questions.Attach(QuestionEnt);
            DataSource.Entry(QuestionEnt).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            DataSource.SaveChanges();

Comment: @LojiSmith, how about the QuestionID value?

Comment: it remains same before and after the operation, its 14

Comment: @LojiSmith, sorry I was wrong, Attach doesn't do anything, you need to mark the state as Modified or get the entity from db, check my updated answer

Comment: so what you updated? you mean should i go for option B? as option A doesn't work

Comment: @LojiSmith, directly change the state, `DataSource.Entry(QuestionEnt).State = EntityState.Modified;` should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57738/discussion-between-lojismith-and-yuliam-chandra).